# forgot password codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, passwords

I tried making forgot password by email using CodeIgniter framework , to send the password change notification email is already working . but after I open the email and click the link to change the password when calling view does not appear .. what's wrong with my script ??

this my controler

```
public function forgot()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_email_check');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
          {
                 $this->load->view('email/email_check');
           }
           else
          {
            $email= $this->input->post('email');

            $this->load->helper('string', 6);
            $rs= random_string('alnum', 12);

            $data = array(
                           'rs' => $rs
                        );
            $this->db->where('email', $email);
            $this->db->update('user', $data);

            //now we will send an email

            $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
                    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                    'smtp_port' => 465,
                    'smtp_user' => 'xxx@xxx.esy.es ',
                    'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxx',
                    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
                    'charset' => 'utf-8',
                    'wordwrap' => TRUE
                );  

                   $this->load->library('email', $config);
                   //$data = array('tes' => 'tester');
                   //$message = $this->load->view('v_email',$data,TRUE);               
                   $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
                   $email_setting  = array('mailtype'=>'html');
                   $this->email->initialize($email_setting);
                   $this->email->from('xx@xx.esy.es', 'xxx');
                   $this->email->to($email);
                   $this->email->subject('Get your forgotten Password');
                   $this->email->message($this->load->view('email/email_forgot', $data, TRUE)); 
                    if($this->email->send())
                    {
                    $data = array ( 'isi' => 'login/vforgot');
                            $this->load->view('layout/wrapper',$data);
                    }else
                    {
                    $data = array ( 'isi' => 'login/vgagal');
                            $this->load->view('layout/wrapper',$data);
                    }               


                   }
}
```

view email sent

```
<tr>
    <td style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;line-height:100%;padding-top:18px;padding-right:15px;padding-bottom:15px;padding-left:15px" align="center" valign="middle">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('/login/register/get_password/index/'.$rs); ?>"style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">Reset Password</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

controllers get_password

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Get_password extends CI_Controller
{
public function index($rs=FALSE)
  {


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[7]|max_length[20]|matches[passconf]|md5');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required');

   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
     {
                  echo form_open();
                  $this->load->view('email/gp_form');

    }
   else
    {
        $query=$this->db->get_where('user', array('rs' => $rs), 1);

       if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
       {
      show_error('Sorry!!! Invalid Request!');
       }  
      else
      {
      $data = array(
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'rs' => ''
      );

      $where=$this->db->where('rs', $rs);

      $where->update('user',$data);

      echo "Congratulations!";
      }

  }

 }

}
```

views gp_form

```
<?php  echo validation_errors();

      echo "Password :".form_password('password', '');
      echo "Password Confirmation :".form_password('passconf', '');
      echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');

?>
```

and this result klik form email

> http://xxxxxx.com/login/register/get_password/index/cfCZm29TPrT6
>
> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

Comment: @bansi , I have tried change `<?php echo site_url('/login/register/get_password/'.$rs); ?>` but it did not work,

Comment: Did you create a route for that `$route['register/get_password/(:any)'] = 'register/get_password/$1'` or `$route['register/get_password/(:any)'] = 'register/get_password/index/$1'` you also do not need to use word index in url. application/config/routes.php  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: You should create a route with that url because it says your are trying to access controller name "login" with method name "register" and args like 'get_password', 'index', and 'cfCZm29TPrT6'. Or you have to change that with the correct url.

Comment: @reignsly thanks but how to repair my problem

Comment: @wolfgang1983  I have tried add route but some  not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats the full URL you are passing? If you getting a 404 it's because your page is missing.

Have you set up friendly urls in your .htaccess? if not then the URL will be

```
http://example.com/index.php/login/register/get_password/index/cfCZm29TPrT6
```

Comment: i using virtual host with xammp and this my .htassess

RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: The Guys are write - your routing is all wrong. You need to follow the MVC - So your controller is /get_password/ - so your url will be `http://example.com/get_password/index/cfCZm29TPrT6`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the route from the `application/config/routes.php` file. The necessary route for this URL would be similar (depending on file structure) to:

```
$route['login/register/get_password/index/(:any)'] = 'get_password/index/$1';
```

Using routing is powerful in CodeIgniter as you could change this quite long URL to something shorter such as http://example.com/login/get_password/cfCZm29TPrT6 using the following routing syntax:

```
$route['login/get_password/(:any)'] = 'get_password/index/$1';
```

You can read more about the routing in the CodeIgniter manual at http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it will work:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('get_password/index/'.$rs); ?>"style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">Reset Password</a>
```